# I'd like to push non-existing items inside an already declared object if they don't already exist using lodash in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I'm new with lodash but as the title states 'I'd like to push non-existing items inside an already declared object if they don't already exist' that is if I have

```
var lessdata = {
    "id": 1004,
    "name": "some event",
    "bookmarked": false        //not in moredata and I'd like to keep the var as is
 };

var moredata = {
    "id": 1004,
    "name": "some event",
    "time": {                       //from here
      "hours": 2,
      "minutes": 00,
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "place": "some place"        //to here is new without '"bookmarked": false'
  };
```

I'd like to have my result loaded back into the `lessdata` variable and have my result look like so

```
var lessdata = {
        "id": 1004,
        "name": "some event",
        "time": {                       
          "hours": 2,
          "minutes": 00,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "place": "some place",
         "bookmarked": false        
  };
```

I stuck knowing know to use lodash apprpriatly in angular and wasnt sure if I need to use angualar's forEach or not.

I've dabbled with two approaches.

> version 1

```
lessdata= _.uniq(lessdata, function(moredata) {
            return moredata;
          });
```

> version 2

```
 angular.forEach(lessdata, function(lkey, lvalue) {
    console.log("[-]lessdata---lkey: " + lkey + ", lvalue: " + lvalue)

    angular.forEach(moredata, function(mkey, mvalue) {
      console.log("[+]moredata---mkey: " + mkey + ", mvalue: " + mvalue)

      lessdata=_.uniq(lessdata, function(moredata) {
        return moredata;
      });

    })
  })
  $scope.event = lessdata
```

Im assuming using `_.uniq` is the best approach? any help would be appreciated and I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/jWeLbe) here.

**TLDR:** just read the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [`lodash.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) does:

> Assigns own and inherited enumerable properties of source objects to the destination object for all destination properties that resolve to `undefined`.

```
lodash.defaults(lessdata, moredata);
```

Comment: wow, that was so simple. I solved it with   _.defaults(lessdata, moredata);

Comment: Yep. I'd suggest to always just browser through the documentation first :)